# Should Spring Rest Service return Map rather than a DTO for JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Because creating a DTO for each request would be painful, I turned it to a map. Is there any other way to return JSON better than this?

```
public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, String> myTest() {    
        Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("a", "1");
        myMap.put("b", "2");
        return myMap;
    }
```

Comment: Well, if you are building REST services, you should not need DTOs as you are manipulating resources, you should simply return those. Or maybe I am missing something and you are doing something really peculiar that requires to manipulate those resources ? In the end I guess that manipulating a Map is not a problem and you might observe something that is repeating that you could put in common in all your responses.

Comment: If you have map with just permanent values and you will never change it, you can create static map on controller creation.  You can also create bean(in your xml or on controller initialisation), authowire it to your controller and return here. In your simple case you can even return `{"a":"1", "b":"2"}` string i think.

Comment: @varren No, it's just example.
@LouisF. Yes i am building REST services, why I should not need DTOs? In my case, I need to return `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. For some other functions, I just need to return  `b`, `c`, `d` or some pieces of them. That's why I refer a map.

Answer (score 1):

I would say better to use DTOs and let Spring/Jackson take care of all the JSon, here is an example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payments", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Payment> batchCreate(@RequestBody List<Payment> payments) {
    return paymentService.create(payments);
}
```

Add Jackson to the classpath

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Or create your own serializer

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String get() throws JsonProcessingException {
    SpecialMap map = new SpecialMap();
    map.put("firstName", "Noby");
    map.put("lastName", "Stiles");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(SpecialMap.class, new MapSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    return serialized;
}

public class MapSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SpecialMap> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(SpecialMap map, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            jgen.writeStringField(key, map.get(key));
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

public class SpecialMap extends HashMap<String,String> {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to do this. But I need to create many Dto classes.

Comment: Updated with content from http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using your entities directly you can also do that. You will need some additional features in jackson though.

- break circular references
- filter properties according to response

For the filtering i have created a small jackson addon that allows for dynamic filtering. Probably it can help:

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter